# PHP file closes browser once script is complete. Need it to display a "download Complete" message

Tags: php, browser

I have a php script which references two other php script. These three scripts are below:

Master Page:

```
    <?php
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;
    filename=huge_document."
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    $FullName = $_GET["FullName"];
    global $FullName;
    Include("Code.php");
    Include ("GetPDFfromServer.php");
    echo ("Download Complete");
    ?>
```

Code.php:

```
<?php
require_once ("fpdf17/fpdf.php");
require_once ('FPDI-1.5.2/fpdi.php');
$pdf =& new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile("Secret.pdf");
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
//use the imported page and place it at point 0,0; calculate width and height
//automatically and adjust the page size to the size of the imported page
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);
// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', '36');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
//set position in pdf document
$pdf->SetXY(195, 240);
//$pdf->Write(0, '|');
$pdf->SetXY(0,240);
$pdf->SetMargins(0,"",0);
//force the browser to download the output
$pdf->Cell(0,0,$FullName,0,0,"C",false,"");
//first parameter defines the line height

$pdf->Output('temp/Secret.pdf', "F");
//return;
?>
```

GetPDFfromServer.php:

```
<?php

//header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf");
//header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("temp/NIA_SM_Policy_Digital-CertificateNEW.pdf");
Echo("Download Complete");
//return;
?>
```

When i load the master page (Eg: www.example/MasterPage.php?FullName=Mark%20Francis) its successfully does all the functions (creates a personalised .pdf, downloads it to the server, then downloads it to the browser). however i would like to display a message saying "download Complete" or something along those lines, but the browser tab closes instantly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You cant do that with PHP. the readfile() function is writing the file into the buffer. you can't add any additional output for the user in the same page. you will need to redirect with JS, or that the download will just be a seperated link instead.

Comment: write this as an answer and i can accept it if you'd like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My updated code for a redirect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
readfile("temp/Secret.pdf");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
</script>


</body>
</html>
```